# Localization of web part label using VS 2010 in a sandbox solution

Tags: sandbox-solution, localization

I have created a sandbox project in sharepoint. I have a  module folder which has resources file.
I need to localize one label in a web part in Arabic language.

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server"   Visible="true"  Text="<%$Resources:TestArabic,ObjectiveCode%>"></asp:Label>
```

The resource file name is TestArabic.ar-SA.resx .
Name: ObjectiveCode
Value: قانون موضوعي

Error: The resource object with key 'ObjectiveCode' was not found.

Comment: You said that the resource is in a module? And you are developing a sandbox solution? Could please post the configuration for the module? does it get deployed correctly?

Comment: Yes resource file is in module and it is a sandbox solution. It is deployed correctly.<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProjectItem Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Module" SupportedTrustLevels="All" SupportedDeploymentScopes="Web, Site" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2010/SharePointTools/SharePointProjectItemModel">
  <Files>
    <ProjectItemFile Source="TestArabic.ar-SA.resx" Target="Test\Module1\" Type="AppGlobalResource" />
    <ProjectItemFile Source="TestEnglish.en-US.resx" Target="Test\Module1\" Type="AppGlobalResource" />
  </Files>
</ProjectItem>

Answer (score 0):

You should place Resource file `TestArabic.ar-SA.resx` on the `App_GlobalResources` folder of your web App by default :

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\<port_number>\App_GlobalResources
```

PS : do not forget to add a default resource file `TestArabic.resx`

Comment: I have the  TestArabic.resx in Resource folder and also placed it in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\<port_number>\App_GlobalResources . Now it says "The resource file '/App_GlobalResources/TestArabic.ar-SA.resx' cannot be used, as it conflicts with another file with the same name"

Comment: try to remove the TestArabic.resx in Resource folder